# Unix: What are stdin/out/err REALLY?

Tags: unix, stream, file-descriptor

Assuming the following are correct...

1. [stdin, stdout, and stderr are streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)
2. [streams are file descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511682/are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-files)
3. [file descriptors are numbers/indexes in the kernel representing open files](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5256599%2Fwhat-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms&ei=GcMAVI7zI8TLggSUwIG4BQ&usg=AFQjCNGQ2R-iSpn7Y2xwcEsGz2pRE4GzZg&sig2=whgfldKKYD4v35JNWJL2ug&bvm=bv.74115972,d.eXY)

Questions:

a. Does it follow by transition that stdin/out/err involve open files? So if I do `ls /dir`, does `ls` output the results to a file referred to by stdout(2)?
b. Where does above file live? in a /proc//? OR is that where the FD lives?
c. What is /dev/stdout? If I do `vim /dev/stdout`, vim tells me it is not a file. I see there's a series of links that lead to `/dev/pts/27`. What is going on? I tried to `cat /dev/stdout` but nothing happens.
d. In general, how is it that "files" in linux are actually NOT files?

Answer (score 2):

Some of your assumptions are incorrect. For example, `stdin` is of type `FILE*`; it's not a "file descriptor".

`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are macros defined in `<stdio.h>`. (Yes, they're required to be macros, not just variable names). They expand to expressions of type `FILE*`, and they point to the `FILE` objects associated with the standard input, output, and error streams.

A "file descriptor" is a small integer value representing a POSIX stream. On UNIX-like systems, `FILE*` values are generally associated with file descriptors (you can use the `fileno` and `fdopen` functions to go from one to the other), but they're not the same thing.

Basically, there are two distinct I/O systems, one built on top of the other. The lower level system uses numeric file descriptors, manipulated via the `open`, `read`, `write`, and `close` functions, and so forth. The higher level, as defined by the ISO C standard, uses pointers of type `FILE*`, manipulated with `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fprintf`, `putchar`, `fclose`, and so forth.

As I mentioned, on UNIX-like system, the C standard layer is generally implemented on top of the POSIX layer. On non-POSIX systems (like MS Windows), the C standard layer may be implemented on top of some other system-specific interface.

Linux and other UNIX-like systems try (incompletely) to follow an "everything is a file" philosophy. There are a number of file-like entities under `/proc`. These are not physical files stored on disk; they're entities that can be accessed using either the POSIX or ISO C I/O layers. Neither layer requires the "files" it deals with to be actual disk files, so there's nothing inconsistent about this.

`man proc` for more information on what's under the `/proc` directory (there's far more detail than I can put in this answer).

Comment: I'm new to this still. Is `FILE*` just a file? If so, where is this file?

Comment: `FILE` is a data type, likely to be a structure. `stderr` is a pointer to a `FILE` object; that object exists somewhere in memory as your program is running. A `FILE` object is not a file; it typically contains information *about* an open file. You dont need to know what's in a `FILE` object, just how to use it by calling the standard functions declared in `<stdio.h>`. Section 12 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) covers stdio, but it's not really written as an introduction. Any decent C textbook or tutorial should tell you what you need to know about it.

Comment: So, to answer my original question (a), stdin/out/err all are not files themselves, but refer to an open Linux file. Is that correct to say, at least from a high level perspective?

Comment: If by "file" you mean an entity external to your program (such as, but not limited to a file stored on a disk), then yes. There's nothing Linux-specific about `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`; they exist in all (hosted) C implementations. On Linux in particular, there happens to be a file-like entity under `/proc` (`/proc/NNN/fd/0`) that corresponds to `stdout for process number `NNN`; that's just the Linux kernel's way of making internal information externally visible. Don't worry too much about `/proc` for now.

Comment: Note also that the external entity that a `FILE*` refers to needn't be a disk file. It can be a pipe, a device, or any of a number of other things.